# ZuulException (SendErrorFilter) at first call

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am building an application by Spring Cloud ,Spring Boot and Docker. Entire application is working fine. I have couple of micro-services. Each of the project is running on Docker. When I try to consume my micro-services through Zuul API Gateway I am getting an error for the 1st call. But if I refresh the browser it's working fine. The error is given below--

```
2019-03-10 04:54:55.440  WARN [netflix- 
zuul-api-gateway- 
server,1855093598d4f99c,1855093598d4f99c
true] 1 --- [nio-8765-exec-1] 
o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   
: Error during filtering


com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException 
at 
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.
filters.post.SendErrorFilter.
findZuulException(SendErrorFilter.java:
114) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul- 
2.1.0.RC3.jar!/:2.1.0.RC3]
at 
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.
filters.post.SendErrorFilter.run
(SendErrorFilter.java:76) ~[spring- 
cloud- 
netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RC3.jar!/
:2.1.0.RC3]
at 
com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter
(ZuulFilter.java:117) [zuul-core- 
1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
at 
com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.
processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.
java:193) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
 at 
com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.
runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) 
[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
at 
com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.error
(FilterProcessor.java:105) [zuul-core- 
1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.error
(ZuulRunner.java:112) [zuul-core- 
1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
at 
com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.error
(ZuulServlet.java:145) [zuul-core- 
1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
at 
com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.servic
e(ZuulServlet.java:83) [zuul-core- 
1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.
Servlet 
letWrappingController.java:165) [spring- 
webmvc- 
5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.spr
```

I have already created the images for all my projects. And push it in the DockerHub. And the Docker-Compose file I also push it in the GitHub. Below is the path.

https://github.com/numery009/DockerCompose/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml

I also deploy it on the Docker Swarm on EC2. 
But When I try to consume my micro-services through Zuul it's not working at all. And I am getting the same "Filter Error" for my every request.

Please help!!!.

Comment: Please try the following URL for Docker-Compose file
https://github.com/numery009/Docker-Compose/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml

Comment: Is this happen as soon as you start the application with docker-compose only  and then it works normally ?

Comment: This is happen for the 1st request through Zuul. I tried in Docker-Compose on my local machine. For the 1st request I am getting the error. Then if I refrsh the browser it's working fine. I also tried on Docker-Swarm on EC2. On EC2 every time I am getting the same Filter Error. For EC2 it's not working. Do I need to change any code?

Comment: I have checked all the services log before send any request through zuul. I am not sending the request immediately. When my all services are up and running then I gave 5 mins more time to warm up docker.  My concern is basically EC2. On EC2 every-time I am getting the same error. What steps can I follow for it to solve?

Comment: how can i reproduce the issue maybe i can figure it out, currently i am running docker-compose up, what should i do next ?

Comment: Hit the following URL and check the log on Zuul container you can see the error.     http://localhost:8765/customer-account-mysql/api/v1/customer-feign

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189782/discussion-between-mostafa-hussein-and-nick).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be 3 things we need to keep on the top of our head for the request which are gone through the Zuul

1) According to this Document - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/1.4.3.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_zuul_eager_application_context_loading

Zuul internally uses Ribbon for calling the remote url’s and Ribbon clients are by default lazily loaded up by Spring Cloud on first call. This behavior can be changed for Zuul using the following configuration and will result in the child Ribbon related Application contexts being eagerly loaded up at application startup time.

application.yaml

```
zuul:
   ribbon:
      eager-load:
         enabled: true
```

application.properties

```
zuul.ribbon.eager-load.enabled= true
```

2) According to this Document - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/single/spring-cloud.html#_service_discovery_configuration

**Service Discovery Configuration** ---
If Zuul is using service discovery there are two timeouts you need to be concerned with, the Hystrix timeout (since all routes are wrapped in Hystrix commands by default) and the Ribbon timeout. The Hystrix timeout needs to take into account the Ribbon read and connect timeout PLUS the total number of retries that will happen for that service. By default Spring Cloud Zuul will do its best to calculate the Hystrix timeout for you UNLESS you specify the Hystrix timeout explicitly.

The Hystrix timeout is calculated using the following formula:

```
(ribbon.ConnectTimeout + ribbon.ReadTimeout) * (ribbon.MaxAutoRetries + 1) * 
(ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer + 1)
```

As an example, if you set the following properties in your application properties

application.yaml

```
ribbon:
   ReadTimeout:100
   ConnectTimeout:500
   MaxAutoRetries:1
   MaxAutoRetriesNextServer:1
```

application.properties

```
ribbon.ReadTimeout= 100
ribbon.ConnectTimeout= 500
ribbon.MaxAutoRetries= 1
ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer= 1
```

Then the Hystrix timeout (for all routes in this case) will be set to 2400ms.

---

In my zuul application config I have added the following properties. And it's working for my 1st call with out any error.

application.yaml

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 11000

ribbon:
   ConnectTimeout: 10000
   ReadTimeout: 10000
```

application.properties

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds= 11000

ribbon.ConnectTimeout= 10000
ribbon.ReadTimeout: 10000
```

3) This is the most easiest way. Disable the hystrix execution time out.

According to this Document -https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#executiontimeoutenabled

Following property will disable the hystrix execution time out on Zuul

application.properties

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false
```

If we keep remember these 3 scenarios then we can easily get the solution of ZuulException (SendErrorFilter).

Answer (score 4):

According to [this documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR1/single/spring-cloud.html#_zuul_eager_application_context_loading):

> Zuul internally uses Ribbon for calling the remote URLs. By default, Ribbon clients are lazily loaded by Spring Cloud on first call. This behavior can be changed for Zuul by using the following configuration, which results eager loading of the child Ribbon related Application contexts at application startup time.

The following example shows how to enable eager loading:

```
# application.yml
zuul:
  ribbon:
    eager-load:
      enabled: true
```

Or

```
# application.properties
ribbon.eager-load.enabled = true
```

You might need to check the following related issues:

- [Ryan Baxter's comment](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3021#issuecomment-413169329)
- [First request through Zuul/Euruka will always timeout. Subsequent requests then behave as expected (no timeouts)](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1783)

Comment: It does not work from me. I have use this property. But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the URL from `localhost` to the service name mentioned in the discovery client.