# Which Spring Cloud Zuul timeout property to use when using the default setup?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, gateway

I'm setting up a (Spring boot 2) Spring cloud zuul/gateway and ran into timeout issues. After reading the [official docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/single/spring-cloud.html#_url_configuration) and checking a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084722/zuulexception-senderrorfilter-at-first-call), I'm not convinced about the proposed solution.

I use the following type of route configuration:

```
routes:
 test-service:
  path: /test-service/**
  serviceId: test-service
```

which I believe to not be "url routes", so I think these properties do not apply:

```
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis
zuul.host.connection-request-timeout-millis
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis
```

I tried setting the properties below, but IntelliJ indicates these properties "do not exist". Is this a quirk in the IDE, or are these properties only present/active under certain circumstances?

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds= 11000
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false
ribbon.ConnectTimeout= 10000
ribbon.ReadTimeout: 10000
```

E.g. see this screenshot from my bootstrap.yml, where it only suggests other properties:
[image]

Is Ribbon and hystrix present and active by default with this maven dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: the ribbon properties from the library do not have auto-completion. You'll have to go to the ribbon wiki to find all available options. https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Programmers-Guide#client-configuration-options

Comment: Did you find solution for your case? I'm having the same problem for timeout, tried both zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=90000 (connect-timeout-millis) and ribbon.SocketTimeout=60000 (ConnectTimeout, ReadTimeout) but neither work :(

Answer (score 5):

If you want to configure timeout in Zuul you have two options ,

If you have configured Zuul to use  service discovery, you need to configure these timeouts with the below  Ribbon properties

```
ribbon.ReadTimeout 
ribbon.SocketTimeout
```

If you have configured Zuul routes by specifying URLs then use below properties ,as per your configuration you need to use this one

```
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis
```

Offical doc is here (Look into Zuul Timeouts section)

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html

Below will show how they  work with Hystrix,

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/single/spring-cloud.html#_service_discovery_configuration

Note : Properties are case sensitive

> I tried setting the properties below, but IntelliJ indicates these
>   properties "do not exist". Is this a quirk in the IDE, or are these
>   properties only present/active under certain circumstances?

May be quirk in the IDE.We have official doc that says the property exits.

Comment: The two sources you provided conflict: one mentions ribbon.ReadTimeout/ribbon.SocketTimeout, the other mentions: ribbon.ReadTimeout/ribbon.ConnectTimeout?

Comment: Yeah. I think we have to use either ribbon.SocketTimeout or ribbon.ReadTimeout

Comment: In the case of using Zuul for service discovery, if you have a service called "service1", and you want all paths `/service1/**` to have a timeout of 1000ms, but the path `/service1/upload/*` to have a higher timeout, say 30,000 ms, how would you configure Ribbon for that?